# CURL share interface and cookies in multi-threaded app

Tags: c, libcurl

I use libcurl share+easy interface and I need to "fix up" some cookie info that is set by a webserver.
In my case I use multiple threads and I would like to know at what point received cookie is "shared" to all other curl handles and when it's the right time to fix received cookie data:

- right when I received it from remote server (but at this point I'm not sure if the corrupt cookie data might be picked up by some other thread that was making a new http request at the same time)
- on making new requests to ensure that I don't end up using corrupt cookie in new http requests.

Here's my code flow. I call `curl_easy_perform`. When response containing `Set-Cookie` comes in, libcurl at first parses that cookie and stores it in its internal store (which gets shared in case of curl share interface).
Then `curl_easy_perform` returns and now I try to check if server send specific cookie that I need to "fix up". To check that cookie the only way is to use `CURLINFO_COOKIELIST`.

My question is: from the time curl parsed incoming `Set-Cookie` header (with invalid cookie data) to the time when I inspect cookies using `CURLINFO_COOKIELIST` the updated invalid cookie might be picked up by another thread. That means that to avoid that issue I don't see any other options other than inspecting cookies on each new request in case if there is another thread out there that might have updated cookies with invalid data.
Even in this case I still may end up using invalid cookie data. In other words, there is no proper solution for this problem.

What's the right approach?

Answer (score 2):

Typically when using libcurl in multiple threads, you use one handle in each thread and they don't share anything. Then it doesn't matter when you modify cookies since each handle (and thus thread) operates independently.

If you make the threads share cookie state, like with the share interface, then you have locking mutexes setup that protects the data objects from being accessed from more than one thread at a time anyway so you can just proceed and update the cookies using the correct API whenever you feel like.

If you're using the multi interface, it does parallel transfers in the same thread and thus you can update cookies whenever you like without risking any problems with parallelisms.

Comment: Hi Daniel, the reason I came to asking this question is because `CURLINFO_COOKIELIST` doesn't actually use that lock. Since in my case I need to retrieve cookies very often (to see if I need to fix them) and I use lots of threads with shared curl handles it becomes threading issue that could easily crash. I use 7.43.0, perhaps this was already fixed in latest versions.

Comment: If it doesn't use the lock, it is a bug.

Comment: Yes, it's a bug, but maybe in latest code it was already fixed. I'll try to make make PR on github

Comment: I created PR with possible fix, and I updated the question

Comment: Note that it's generally pointless to use multiple threads with curl, since curl knows how to multiplex *without* threads.

Comment: @o11c you mean multi interface? I know about that, but in my case I cannot simply switch that as I have cross-platform code that uses threaded approach and culr based impl is used where it can be used. On xbox for example I cannot use curl

Comment: @Pavel you could merely use threads to (block and) send a request to the main libcurl event loop.

Comment: @o11c I use threads and simply make blocking call from them using `curl_easy_perform`. Are you suggesting something else?

Comment: @Pavel it will *probably* be better to use a single dedicated thread with CurlMulti to do all the actual I/O, but hide that from your callers for simplicity/compatibility. Basically like using futures with a thread pool and then immediately waiting for them.

Comment: @o11c I'm planning to rewrite my http code with curl multi interface, but that mainly depends on outside code, which is complex and risky to update